# SPLUNK behavior during network failure

Tags: java, tcp, playframework, splunk

What would happen to the logs being sent to SPLUNK when there is a network failure? I am sending data to SPLUNK through my Java application using TCP. Are there any solutions provided for this from SPLUNK side?

Answer (score 0):

You will get error details in splunkd.log file , data you have sent goes to queues in splunk and if network broken then latest data will not come to splunk in your case, you have to resend the data.
with splunk forwarder if network down and then up data will come correctly as it is buffered in forwarder side